# How to use subforms in Zend Framework2

Tags: zend-framework2, subforms

Is there a way how I can use zend subforms in Zend Framework2. When I did a search in the internet I have landed upon many examples showing how to use zend subforms but using Zend Framework1.

In case if somebody has a link/example where one can go through a basic example, would be great.

Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Zend\Form is tree structure, you could add another form into your form with a form name. Such like this:

```
$form = new \Zend\Form\Form();
$form->add(array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
));

$subForm = new \Zend\Form\Form();
$subForm->setName('subform');
$subForm->add(array(
    'name' => 'email',
    'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
));

$form->add($subForm);

$form->prepare();

$helper = new Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormText();
echo $helper($form->get('username')); //<input type="text" name="username" value="">
echo $helper($form->get('subform')->get('email')); //<input type="text" name="subform[email]" value="">
```

Notice that the "subform" input name will be add form name as prefix automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using it for a few hours, and in my understanding, zf1 subforms funcionalities are solved in zf2 by using nested fieldsets.

`\Zend\Form\Fieldset` is also the parent class of `\Zend\Form\Form`.

The previous answer seems correct to me, but if you prefer to keep forms and subforms in separate classes, read this:

http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html

Ignore the entity and hydration stuff if you are not interested for now, and look at `CreateProduct` class, it's a form that uses the FieldSet `ProductFieldset` as a subform. At rendering time, subform fields will be named like

```
<input ...name="product[el1]" ... >
```

(where `product` is the name of the subform).
And $form->getData() will return

```
array('product'=>array(...))
```

Note: you need to call `$form->prepare()`; before rendering, or the nesting won't be processed.